# Why A Variable's Value Changes

Tags: java

I do not understand why the value of `smallCountLoopCount` changes from 0 to 1 in the code provided.  I expect it to remain at 0.  I use IntelliJ IDEA for testing.  I have two statements to audit the values.  Each are:

```
System.out.println("SMALL LOOP COUNT = " + smallCountLoopCount);
```

The first prints 0 and the second prints 1.  What do I need to change to have the second one print 0?

I've tried working the `()` brackets to try and ensure that the math flows correctly, doing the multiplication first and then the addition second.  It looks like the addition piece is incrementing the variable instead of doing math with it??

```
while (bigCountLoopCount <= bigCount) {
    //System.out.println(bigCountLoopCount + " " + smallCountLoopCount);
    if ((bigCountLoopCount * 5) == goal) {
        //System.out.println("THIS TRUE ACTIVATED");
        return true;
    }
    System.out.println("SMALL LOOP COUNT = " + smallCountLoopCount);
    if (((bigCountLoopCount * 5) + smallCountLoopCount) == goal)
    {
        System.out.println("SMALL LOOP COUNT = " + smallCountLoopCount);
        System.out.println("THIS TRUE ACTIVATED by:");
        System.out.println(bigCountLoopCount + " " + smallCountLoopCount + " " + goal);
        return true;
    }
    smallCountLoopCount++;
    bigCountLoopCount++;
}
```

Expected result:

```
SMALL LOOP COUNT = 0  
SMALL LOOP COUNT = 0
```

Actual result:

```
SMALL LOOP COUNT = 0  
SMALL LOOP COUNT = 1
```

Comment: Where are those values declared?

Can you clarify which one is zero and which one is one at your result? You are stating that smallCountLoopCount equals zero and one at the same time.

Comment: Have you tried changing the two `println` statements to print different text to make sure it isn't just the first one executing twice?

Comment: `smallCountLoopCount++;` increases the value. If you don't think this line should be excuted, please debug your application. Set a breakpoint at the line `smallCountLoopCount++;` and see why.

Comment: You are aware that the two printed lines comes from the same code line?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have `smallCountLoopCount++;` at the end of the loop body. And apparently it doesn't hit neither of the returns.

If you change to `goal=0` and `bigCount=0` then you will get your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You have at the bottom of your while loop:

```
smallCountLoopCount++;
```

This is not surrounded by any condition so will always be executed. It is hard to see what exactly you're trying to do without the full piece of code, but if you want smallCountLoopCount to remain at zero, remove the above such as follows:

```
                //System.out.println(bigCountLoopCount + " " + smallCountLoopCount);
                if ((bigCountLoopCount * 5) == goal) {
                    //System.out.println("THIS TRUE ACTIVATED");
                    return true;
                }
                System.out.println("SMALL LOOP COUNT = " + smallCountLoopCount);
                if (((bigCountLoopCount * 5) + smallCountLoopCount) == goal)
                {
                    System.out.println("SMALL LOOP COUNT = " + smallCountLoopCount);
                    System.out.println("THIS TRUE ACTIVATED by:");
                    System.out.println(bigCountLoopCount + " " + smallCountLoopCount + " " + goal);
                    return true;
                }
                // smallCountLoopCount++ was here - Anything in this area will be executed regardless
                bigCountLoopCount++;
            }
```